# What is a "Teaching District"?

Tags: meaning

A [post](https://www.ck12.org/statistics/confidence-intervals/lesson/Confidence-Intervals-ADV-PST/) says

> In a local **teaching district**, a technology grant is available to teachers

I am aware of the meaning of "teaching" and "district" respectively.

However, "teaching district" seems to refer to special area. I googled it but didn't found a definition or explanation.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a local term for what might be also called a school district; the schools in a certain part of a country or state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A district is a *territorial division*. The same area of land can be divided, virtually, a number of different ways for different purposes and these divisions may be referred to as 'districts'.

For example, a 'postal district' is an area which may be served by a particular postal service, or that shares a post code. The borders of this district may have nothing at all to do with town or city borders.

'Teaching District' logically sounds like an area that is served by a particular education authority.